# Removing broken tags and poorly formatted html from some text

Tags: python, html-parsing

i have a huge database of scraped forum posts that i am inserting into a website. however alot of people try to use html in their forum posts and often times do it wrong. because of this, there are always stray `<strike> <b> </strike>  </div> </b>` tags in the posts which will end up messing up the webpage format when i add say 15 forum posts.

for now i have just been appending all possible end tags to the post just so that it might catch any open tag...is there a better way to do this short of parsing through the text and trying to manually remove each open tag. for loooooong forum posts this is an expensive transaction for a web app.

Comment: If you are adding HTML content from untrusted users you have much worse problems than just accidentally-unclosed elements. Endless cross-site-scripting security holes are coming your way. Use a full HTML parser, remove all elements and attributes that aren't whitelisted, and store the clean serialised results in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [HTML Tidy](http://www.w3.org/People/Raggett/tidy/)

There is a also a Python wrapper lib: [µTidylib](http://utidylib.berlios.de/)

Alternatively there is [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/)

Answer (score 0):

[Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) does a decent job at HTML cleanup.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [`lxml`](http://codespeak.net/lxml/) also.